# HBase Cluster does not work

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

Hbase does not work in cluster mode.
Regionserver Web UI says

> "RegionServer is starting..."

Error on HBase logs

> Failed to connect to regionserver. Timeout reached

Error on HBase Web UI

> table goes into failed regions automatically and then is not accessible from HBase shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for errors in the ***hbase-USER-master-HOST.log*** and ***hbase-USER-regionserver-HOST.log*** and post the error here.
Also, make sure you are able to ping all the regionservers and master using the hostnames.